# How can I add an option for already existing accounts to sign-in instead of signing up for a new account in an app that uses Google Sign-In

Tags: java, android, firebase, google-cloud-platform, firebase-authentication

I'm trying to create the registration page for my app that uses Google Sign-In as the credentials, but I want to add an option at the starting page for Google Accounts that were already registered. Like "Already an existing user? Sign In". I'm also using Firebase Authentication for this.

Here is my code for the Sign-Up page:

```
@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

    signin = findViewById(R.id.signin);
    requestGoogleSignIn();

    signin.setOnClickListener(view -> signIn());
    mAuth = FirebaseAuth.getInstance();


}

@Override
protected void onStart(){
    super.onStart();
    FirebaseUser user = mAuth.getCurrentUser();
    if (user != null){
        startActivity(new Intent(MainActivity.this, MainActivity2.class));
    }
}


private void requestGoogleSignIn()
{
    GoogleSignInOptions gso = new GoogleSignInOptions.Builder(GoogleSignInOptions.DEFAULT_SIGN_IN)
            .requestIdToken(getString(R.string.default_web_client_id))
            .requestEmail()
            .build();

    mGoogleSignInClient = GoogleSignIn.getClient(this, gso);
}

private void signIn() {
    Intent signInIntent = mGoogleSignInClient.getSignInIntent();
    startActivityForResult(signInIntent, RC_SIGN_IN);
}


@Override
public void onActivityResult(int requestCode, int resultCode, Intent data) {
    super.onActivityResult(requestCode, resultCode, data);

    // Result returned from launching the Intent from GoogleSignInApi.getSignInIntent(...);
    if (requestCode == RC_SIGN_IN) {
        Task<GoogleSignInAccount> task = GoogleSignIn.getSignedInAccountFromIntent(data);
        try {
            // Google Sign In was successful, authenticate with Firebase
            GoogleSignInAccount account = task.getResult(ApiException.class);

            firebaseAuthWithGoogle(account.getIdToken());
            SharedPreferences.Editor editor = getApplicationContext()
                    .getSharedPreferences("MyPrefs", MODE_PRIVATE)
                    .edit();
            editor.putString("username", account.getDisplayName());
            editor.putString("useremail",account.getEmail());
            editor.putString("userphoto", account.getPhotoUrl().toString());

        } catch (ApiException e) {
            // Google Sign In failed, update UI appropriately
            Toast.makeText(MainActivity.this,"Authentication Failed" + e.getMessage(), Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
        }
    }
}



private void firebaseAuthWithGoogle(String idToken) {
    AuthCredential credential = GoogleAuthProvider.getCredential(idToken, null);
    mAuth.signInWithCredential(credential)
            .addOnCompleteListener(this, task -> {
                if (task.isSuccessful()) {
                    // Sign in success, update UI with the signed-in user's information
                            Intent intent = new Intent(MainActivity.this, UserProfileChangeRequest.class);
                            startActivity(intent);
                } else {
                    // If sign in fails, display a message to the user.
                    Toast.makeText(MainActivity.this,"Authentication Failed", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                }
            });
}
```

}

Comment: What exactly in this code doesn't work the way you expect?
Tell us what is wrong with shared code. Do you have any errors?

Comment: There aren't errors with the code itself, but I haven't seen any posts so far on the Internet to add that option when it comes to Google Sign-In.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Since you authenticate your users with Firebase using Google credentials, you can check whether a user signs in for the first time or not. This can simply be done by using the following lines of code:

```
FirebaseAuth auth = FirebaseAuth.getInstance();
auth.signInWithCredential(credential).addOnCompleteListener(this, new OnCompleteListener<AuthResult>() {
    @Override
    public void onComplete(@NonNull Task<AuthResult> task) {
        boolean isNewUser = task.getResult().getAdditionalUserInfo().isNewUser();
        if (isNewUser) {
            Log.d(TAG, "The user is new.");
        } else {
            Log.d(TAG, "The user is already registered");
        }
    }
});
```